# Why is GETDATE slowing down select query if I use a variable?

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing a select on a table with about 6 millions records selecting `GETDATE()`

```
select getdate() as date, [...] from MyTable
```

I verified that the performance issue is on `GETDATE()`, removing all other fields the query is still slow.

I thought that putting the value of `GETDATE()` in a separate var would speed the query up

```
declare @now datetime
set @now = GETDATE()
select @now as date, [...] from MyTable
```

It is slow as well. Why?

Comment: `removing all other fields the query is still slow` -  did you also remove the `where` condition?

Comment: @GSerg there is no where condition at all

Comment: Have you examined the query plan in both cases to see if there are any significant differences?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the GETDATE() has anything to do with the query being slow, but the fact that it returns 6 million rows. Try returning a constant : select 1 as constant from MyTable. If it's still slow then the problem is not the returned values but the size of the dataset.

Comment: @MarcGuillot selecting 1 is fast (1.2 s) while selecting getdate is slow. That's why I'm asking the question

Comment: Then you should compare the execution plans, as @StewartRitchie said

Comment: @MarcGuillot even if simply doing `select field from table`? There are no join or where clauses

Comment: It's just to rule out something weird happening - they should both have the same query plan apart from a variable assignment

Comment: Rendering 6M rows in SSMS will be the slowest bit (if that's what you are doing), try comparing when you insert in to a temp table

Comment: Different data types - `date` vs `datetime` - datetime representation has more characters and sending those over takes time.

Comment: @Arvo `date` is the column name, not the type. The type is `datetime` in both cases. And in both cases it's the date itself that's being sent, not its text representation.

Comment: Well, sorry, I misread then :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd never really noticed this before. But I am seeing the same thing.

Ran the following on a 10 million row table...

```
-- query #1
DECLARE @now AS DATETIME ;
SET     @now = GETDATE() ;
SELECT  @now AS [date], * FROM [MyTable] ;
-- cpu time = 2,563 ms
-- duration = 27,511 ms

-- query #2
SELECT  GETDATE() AS [date], * FROM [MyTable] ;
-- cpu time = 2,421 ms  
-- duration = 26,862 ms

-- query #3
SELECT  * FROM [MyTable] ;
-- cpu time = 1,969 ms  
-- duration = 23,149 ms
```

And the cpu times and durations are showing a difference.

All three query plans are more or less the same, with negligible difference between estimated costs for the queries.

The only differences I could see between the plans were the wait stats...

*Query #1*

- WaitType = ASYNC_NETWORK_IO
- WaitCount = 77,716
- WaitTimeMs = 24,234

*Query #2*

- WaitType = ASYNC_NETWORK_IO
- WaitCount = 75,261
- WaitTimeMs = 23,662

*Query #3*

- WaitType = ASYNC_NETWORK_IO
- WaitCount = 55,434
- WaitTimeMs = 20,280

That's an extra 3-4 seconds, between including and not including the GETDATE() column in the result set, just waiting for whatever's running the query to acknowledge it has consumed the data and is ready for more.

In my case, I was using SSMS to execute the queries. So, I can only put it down to SSMS dragging its heels to render that extra column, which amounted to about 75 MB (10M x 8 bytes).

Having said that, the bulk of the time is obviously taken up with scanning all 10 million rows.

Unfortunately, I think the extra execution time to include your GETDATE() column is unavoidable.

Comment: OP actually asked, why using `getdate()` instead of date variable is faster - you didn't answer that.

Comment: @Arvo No, the OP asked why both getdate() and a datetime variable are equally slow, but removing them makes it fast.

Comment: Hmm, thread caption (why is getdate slowing down select query if I use a variable) indicated different question (I could not exactly decide, what OP really asked - maybe I got that wrong :)). Your answer shows that using either getdate or variable result in similar times, query without that column is faster - that was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Two points.

- ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is SQL Server saying that it is waiting for network bandwidth to be available in order to send more data down the pipe.
- SSMS stores the output of the Results window in a temp file on your C:\ drive so will be affected by disk I/O, AV scanning, other processes, etc. running on your machine. Same concept if you use a Linux OS.

I'd experiment with limiting the size of the data being returned (10M records can hardly be analysed by a human), and using a different tool to pull the records (if you really need 10M records) for starters.
Also, review the Execution Plan to find out where exactly the delay is. If it still points yo the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait, then your problem could be one or more of the network components between yourself and the server. Try using a wired connection instead of WiFi. Do you have a VPN? Is there anything limiting data transfer rates? Or the reason might simply be that too much data is being pulled.